# How can I choose a specific style of google family-font?

Tags: html, css, font-family, google-font-api

Google's font families each have more than one style, how can I choose a specific style from the styles I've chosen from this family to style a specific HTML element?
how can I know their CSS value?
I know you need to add the  tag to the  and there are CSS rules to specify families available but they are general for the family font, I want to choose a style from the family font.
[Google font-family with its styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaJxU.png)
Hope what I meant was clear.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: So from what I understand, you need to choose a specific font from those selections?

Comment: yes, how to choose a certain style of the family since it has more than one style? how to address it in CSS value

Answer (score 0):

Those are either italic or different font weights of the same font family, so for example if you need in your project a font weight of 700, 400 and 300, you select those, so that when you use them in your code, they will be available. And the transpiler won't go look for another family that you added as second or third to find the good style. Hope that makes sense

Comment: for example, I want a <h1> to have the bold 700 style of this family
how would I address it in CSS? 
h1 {font-family: what the CSS value in here for the bold 700 style? ;}

Comment: you should simply set the font-weight property to 700

Comment: if you didn't selected it when importing the font, the transpiler would go look for the second font-family in your list and grab that styling

Comment: so two CSS properties to get the style
Got it, thanks!